# Cannot use echo after connection to database

Tags: javascript, php, postgresql, echo

I'm using ajax to send a request to php with some text.

```
$.get("process.php", { finalQuery : finalQuery }, function(data) {

alert("Data Loaded: " + data);

});
```

I know this works because in php I can put

```
$val = $_GET['finalQuery']; echo $val;
```

And it outputs the correct data.
However, if I put

```
$db = pg_Connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=Blah user=postgres password=1888");

pg_close($db);
```

It stops echoing the results back to javascript. If I use a different port or name, and it doesn't connect, it then goes back to sending the data to javascript and outputting the correct data.

So basically, when I connect to the database, I cannot communicate my results back with echo. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT(update):**
Here's the complete php code

```
    <?php
$val = $_GET['finalQuery'];
echo $val;

$db = pg_Connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=Blah user=postgres password=1888");
$result = pg_query($db, 'SELECT gid FROM "Perfect"');
while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
  echo "gid: $row[0]";
  echo "<br />\n";
}

pg_close($db);
?>
```

However, the problem still occurs as long as I use pg_connect. All the other lines can be removed and the problem persists. As long as I remove the pg_connect, the problem disappears and I can send the information back through echo

**NEW EDIT(debugging) :**

The connection to the database and the php code seems ok. After loading the php page with

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
```

no errors are logged on the page, and the connection to the database is returning all the data properly on every page load.

The problem arises when I'm trying to connect to the php through javascript.

The page loads the data properly sometimes, but it's random, and most of the time nothing happens (not even php logged errors). If you there's no way the javascript-php connection isn't the problem then I'll keep debugging the code.

Comment: Can you pleas provide the rest of the relevant PHP code? There is very likely a fatal error occurring.

Comment: It's not that C is capital, I tried using pg_connect instead, same error. Also, after reloading the page 7-8 times, I get a correct response from the server.

Comment: *If I use a different port or name, and it doesn't connect, it then goes back to sending the data to javascript and outputting the correct data.* How does intentionally not connection to you DB output the correct data?

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that if I use echo "hello" in php, it returns to javascript as a result. If I connect to the database, even the "hello" echo gets dumped, along with the database data. If I connect to the wrong port or with the wrong name, the echo "hello" outputs properly into javascript.

It's like connecting to the database ruins the whole echo command and only works with 1/10 chance.

Comment: How do you handle errors? Your code makes the assumption that everything will be fine and nothing can go wrong. But this topic proves otherwise.... Start error handling, let you code check everything. Did it connect to the database? Could it execute the query? Is there a result set? What error did you get if something went wrong? etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the steps I'd take for debug:

1. Begin by ensuring the DB is running and that you can send it a query
   successfully via console window DB GUI Tool (Navicat is my gui of
   choice for DB's)
2. Load the PHP page directly.  Check for output of
   expected code or fatal PHP Errors
3. Check the browser console for errors.  Since it appears to be a PHP
   only page, this should be entirely clear of problems.
4. Check PHP logs
5. Check Postgres logs

More than likely, something between Postgres and PHP is the problem.  Post any errors back on your question if you're still stuck after finding a clue.